# How do I style parenthesis so they don't hang beneath the other characters next to them

Tags: html, css

If I have this text below with parenthesis, is there a way to style them so the parenthesis don't hang below the other characters?

```html
<span> Some text <span style = "font-size: .7em;">(other text)</span></span>
```

Comment: Note that they hang below the line even without your second span: https://jsfiddle.net/y6tkvmr2/. The true answer is: use a font where those glyphs (left and right parentheses) aren't placed like that.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I'm using a different font size in my project, so a quick copy and paste was used. So basically I should use a different font?

Comment: Submitted an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parentheses hanging below the line is a decision of the font. Truthfully, if you want this, you would be better off manually editing the font you use so that the two glyphs start on the baseline. However, this will make them look silly next to letters with descenders like "q" or "y".

Confused what "baseline" and "descenders" mean? [Here's a handy reference](https://m2.material.io/design/typography/understanding-typography.html#type-properties):

[image: an image of a typeface, with labels for each part - e.g. de]

Let's say you're not going to edit the font, though, as that's rather extreme! So what you're really asking is: "how do I position individual characters in a sentence?" The answer is either with relative positioning, or with `translateY()`, which I prefer.

Note that this will make the *top* of the parentheses ascend comically above the baseline, and that the offset amount I use here will be a different value depending on the font chosen (here, Times New Roman).

```css
.raise-baseline {
  display: inline-block;
  /* `em` so that positioning is accurate for other font sizes */
  /* note that the exact amount depends on the font - this will only be accurate for Times New Roman */
  transform: translateY(-.12em);
}

/* demo styles */
body {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a line (with a regular parenthesis).</p>

<p>And here's one <span class="raise-baseline">(</span>with an adjustment<span class="raise-baseline">)</span>.</p>
```

Comment: I would suggest the same !

Comment: Thanks. You're explanation really helps in understanding. One question - Do you know any good fonts I can use that don't have any descenders? Not sure if that's the correct wording, but any characters that hang below the baseline?

Comment: That's exactly the correct wording! And truthfully, I do not. That would be a very specialized font. But Google is your friend! You could also try looking for "fixed height" fonts.

Comment: Do you know anything about using different fonts in a project and copyright issues? I ask because I want to use a font that's nicer (ex. Circular) than the default ( New Times Roman or Helvetica I think) but I don't want to pay for Circular. I found some of the files for Circular font online and have plugged them into my site and it works, but I don't know if I should use it because I might get into trouble or...? Question - How would the owner of Circular font know if I can use it or not? Would they just happen to see my site and say, "hey they didn't pay us for our font!" ? Then they sue?

Comment: There are many great free fonts. Don't illegally use one that isn't free. This is not really the venue for this discussion, however. Consider e.g. https://reddit.com/r/webdev/